# SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Authentication

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNTLM/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
<EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

Whenever I have the above settings in my rsreportserver.config file I can view reports in my web application but I can't access the Report Manager.

But whenever I have the settings below I can't view the reports in my web application but I can access the Report Manager. What settings should I use to be able to access both?

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsBasic/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
<EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you've already seen these items, but I thought I would pass along just in case they are useful or anyone else needs them:

http://blogs.msdn.com/brianhartman/archive/2008/11/21/custom-credentials-in-the-report-viewer.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/jameswu/archive/2008/07/15/anonymous-access-in-sql-rs-2008.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159272%28SQL.90%29.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/microsoftbob/archive/2009/08/20/a-wrapper-for-running-sql-server-2008-reporting-services-reports-anonymously.aspx